# Run Django cause Pycharm behave unexpectedly

Tags: python, django, pycharm

After running `python manage.py runserver` in terminal, PyCharm behave unexpectedly. Code analysis stop working and after restart PyCharm it hangs and only compute reboot fix issue.

PyCharm Professional 2019.2.1
MacOS 10.14.6